# C# size of a linked list (source code)

Tags: c#

I'm in my second year in computer science. Our teacher asked us to implement the class MyLinkedList (even tough it exists by default in C#) to improve our programming skills (Algorithms).

I was able to implement a good part of the code and test it, but I was not able to implement the function that returns the size of the linked list.

This is what I've done to far :

```cs
class MyLinkedList
{

    class Element
    {
        public float value;
        public Element next;
    }


    Element first;

    public MyLinkedList()
    {
        first = null;
    }

    public void add(float x)
    {
        Element e = new Element();
        e.value = x;
        e.next = first;
        first = e;
    }

    public float get(int i)
    {
        if (first == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Empty list...no elements inside");
        }
        Element tmp = first;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            tmp = tmp.next;
            if (tmp == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("...");
            }
        }
        return tmp.value;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        // I'm completely lost on that one, I have no clue on how
        // doing it.
    }

}
```

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //To test the code

        MyLinkedList l = new MyLinkedList();
        l.add(3);
        l.add(5);
        l.add(8);
        Console.WriteLine(l.get(0));
        Console.WriteLine(l.get(1));
        Console.WriteLine(l.get(4));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just `increment` count when you add item and `decrement` when you remove it.

Comment: Why do you change **first** each time you add an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
 public int size()
{
     Element tmp = first;
     int cnt =0;
     while(temp != null)
     {
         cnt++;
         temp = temp.next
     }
      return cnt;

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I spent 2 hours trying to figure it out ^^

Answer (score 1):

I am not at my development machine, so I haven't tried this:

```
public int Count()
{
     int count = 0;
     Element e = first
     while(e != null)
     {
          ++count;
          e =e.next;
     }
     return count;
}
```

That is the kinnd of thing you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I just tested it and it works just fine :)

Comment: Great  - see someone beat me to it! I find laptop keyboards incredibly difficult to type in, and I have just edited the wrong post. I hope whoever is reviewing the edit will revert it to whatever was originally posted!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a field to keep track of the size? You can increment it when adding elements and decrement it on removing.

```
class MyLinkedList
{
    int size = 0;

    public void add(float x)
    {
        size++;
        ....
    }

    public void remove(float x)
    {
        size--;
        ...
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }
```

It's only an idea.. of course you have to check whether you have really added or removed the element. eg: you are trying to remove an element that is not in the list). Doing like that you can avoid to calculate the size everytime the size method is  called.

Comment: The idea is not bad at all! I'll do it it. It will be more practical than to calculate the size each time I change the elements in the list. Thank you :)